# Deriving XPath for accessing table elements

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to scrape the table from this [website](http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-gainnnm-gainer.html) using HtmlAgilityPack and a C# Console App.

I am able to scrape the names of the stocks in Column 2 (ex: EDAP TMS ADR (EDAP) but I am not being able to get the correct XPath for any of the values from the Price, Chg, Chg% columns.

For ex:
My XPath for the names column works perfectly as:

```
"//*[@id=\"column0\"]//div//table//tr//td//a"
```

What would be the XPath for the Price, Chg, Chg% columns? 
Can you help me understand how you would derive it?

Comment: Something along this lines might help: `//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the xpath to get the desired column output, based on column name.

For price: Getting price from 4th row.

```
//div[@class='mdcNarrowM']//table//tr[4]/td[count(ancestor::table[1]//tr[1]/td[.='Price']/preceding-sibling::td)+1]
```

General Notation in this case: (update the row number and column names as per your need) Tested for all the columns in that table.

```
//div[@class='mdcNarrowM']//table//tr[row_number_goes_here]/td[count(ancestor::table[1]//tr[1]/td[.='column name goes here']/preceding-sibling::td)+1]
```

To get all the rows (except the header row) use this below xpath.

```
//div[@class='mdcNarrowM']//table//tr[not(td[@class='colhead'])]/td[count(ancestor::table[1]//tr[1]/td[.='Price']/preceding-sibling::td)+1]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. 
I am able to get the collection, however the collection returned also contains the name of the row (which is 'Price'). While I can tweak my code to just load values from the 2nd element onwards, I was wondering if you could tell me how to strip the column name by modifying the XPath instead.

This is what I am currently using in my code:


"//div[@class = 'mdcNarrowM']//table//tr//td[count(ancestor::table//tr//td[.='Price']//preceding-sibling::td)+1]"

Comment: Yes, I can be done with the xpath. Updated the answer with the xpath to get all rows except the header. Check and let me know.